# In PHP, can ceil() ever round up an even division?

Tags: php, rounding

I have read a bunch of questions and comments but haven't seen this mentioned, and since others may have the same question, I'm posting it here.

Considering floating point errors, is it ever possible to get a result one point higher than it should be from a `ceil($a / $b)` where the rest of `$a / $b` is 0?

If so, since I'm working with positive integers higher than 0, perhaps I should write my_ceil() where I check for `$a % $b` first and if it's not 0, add 0.1 to $a before calling the built-in function…

Comment: sooo... are you working with integers or floats? As you reference both in your question . What does trial and error give you?

Comment: There has not been any trial and error since I wanted to post the results publicly. As stated, in my current project, I'm only using positive integers above 0, but the question is for floats as well.

Answer (score 1):

If what you appear to be asking is how to use floating points including their correct non-absolute errors in deciding a `ceil` outcome, the following should guide you:

1. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

> Rational numbers that are exactly representable as floating point
> numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an exact
> representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is used
> internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they cannot be
> converted into their internal binary counterparts without a small loss
> of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for example,
> floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the expected 8,
> since the internal representation will be something like
> 7.9999999999999991118....
>
> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and *do not
> compare floating point numbers directly for equality* [my emphasis]. If higher
> precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp functions are available.

Read up

**Arbitrary precision math functions** : https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php

And **gmp** : https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php

2. You are caring about floats (as the single input value) when using `ceil($float)` when *ceil will only ever round up to the nearest integer* so whatever the floating value is, is irrelevant. You may be considering using the `round()` function instead. which has it's own ways of dealing with the above floating point inaccuracy issue.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

---

To answer the original question of **Considering floating point errors, is it ever possible to get a result one point higher than it should be from a `ceil($a / $b)` where the rest of `$a / $b` is 0?** the answer is YES because of two points:

- Float is potentially significantly inaccurate in base10 numbers, and,
- You are using the wrong function to get the output you want to the precision you need. In this situation using multiple float numbers you want a function that have built in precision required, such as [gmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) or [maths functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) .

Comment: 1) I mentioned "floating point errors" so I obviously know about that. 2) Sorry, don't understand this at all. Thanks for the answer, though, and since I'm only dividing integers, to my understanding, ceil() should work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [ceil source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/71c19800258ee3a9548af9a5e64ab0a62d1b1d8e/ext/standard/math.c) on github, it seems that it is dependent on your C library's ceil function.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: To answer the question – YES, it (probably) can.

I guess this doesn't really have anything to do with ceil() but rather with if the division in question returns a float or integer type value.

According to http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php …

> The division operator ("/") returns a float value unless the two operands are integers (or strings that get converted to integers) and the numbers are evenly divisible, in which case an integer value will be returned.

So using at least one float value could produce a ceil() "error", but I should be fine with two integers.

Comment: There is something you missed..The division of two integer is not always an integer..

Comment: Did I misunderstand something or are you saying the documentation is wrong? I don't care about float returns when the remainder is not 0, only when it is.

Comment: I think your answer is incorrect -- "probably" is not really a term for an answer. If something "probably " can or not, then that bares little to no important relationship as to ***if it actually does***. Also I feel your answer is far more specific than your question appears to be and that niggles me, to be honest. Your answer delves specifically into division but your question seemed to be more about general arithmetic within a float number result.

Comment: There is type-juggling in php..Php does'nt support defining a type like java,etc..So probably the result of 1/5 is a "double" but it's "juggling" to a float in ceil() function..

Comment: Yeah, my fault there, but if you'd focused on answering the question at hand, this would've been far less messy… and the quote in my answer is still the only thing that really helped.

Comment: **In PHP, can ceil() ever round up an even division?** Short answer: YES. The long answer points out that the result depends on the argument.